# htaccess rule rewrite .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My client old webpage has `www.domain.com/client/default.asp?wa_id=558&wa_object_id=1&wa_id_key=25092d5959fd9f212d5c0f63a5f0efb2` kind of URLs.

Now we have installed a new CMS and we want to main keep old URLs by converting URLs.

I want to write .htacess URL what does next

```
client/default.asp?wa_id=558&wa_object_id=1&wa_id_key=25092d5959fd9f212d5c0f63a5f0efb2
```

converts to

```
index.php?id=client/default.asp?wa_id=558&wa_object_id=1&wa_id_key=25092d5959fd9f212d5c0f63a5f0efb2
```

I tried this but

```
RewriteRule ^client/(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

result is

```
index.php?id=client/default.asp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add **QSA** flag:

```
RewriteRule ^client/(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa